# Battery charge not updating, always whatever it was at startup

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, 22.10

After installing 22.10 on a new laptop, the battery charge (indicator) never changes. It is charging just fine though, but `upower` shows the wrong value.

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               DYNAPACK
  model:                HB4692J5ECW-31
  serial:               1823
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fr 04 Nov 2022 14:43:25 CET (1 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         42,2645 Wh
    energy-full-design:  41,4279 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             10,062 V
    charge-cycles:       24
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

and

```
$ busctl call --system org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1 org.freedesktop.UPower.Device Refresh
Call failed: Method Refresh is not implemented on interface org.freedesktop.UPower.Device
```

I guess that error is why it does not update.

```
UPower client version 0.99.20 
UPower daemon version 0.99.20
```

(I have seen reports that downgrading to 0.99.17 could help, however I have not been able to try that, because of the many dependency issues)

Restarting using `sudo systemctl restart upower.service` does not update the value, only after a complete reboot it shows the correct value.

**UPDATE**
Turns out that power for the wireless mouse was not working either.
And acpi did not update, including the temp sensor, which seems a bit dangerous.
*Solution:*

Installed 22.04 again and now it all works as it should.

Comment: To be clear Upower is not updating but the battery is charging? What does it say in the OS about power under settings?

Comment: David , yes. It is annoying, because when unplugged, it shuts down unexpectedly after about 6hours, while still showing 100% :)  Under settings it shows the same value (not updating) . Nothing in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/*` seems to update after (un)plugging the cable.

Comment: For upower you may want to ask the upower people. For the OS maybe file a bug report. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting